# How to run a function on close in a Chrome App?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I'm having an issue where closing my Chrome App too quickly after completing a stage corrupts the save data. This is because it's in the middle of saving some data.

Is there any way to keep the Chrome App open for a few seconds after the user presses close or alt+f4? Or another solution that maybe has a popup telling the user that the app is saving and will close automatically?

Comment: send data to background and save it there... background is kept around 10 seconds after app is closed and then goes to "sleep"...  just a thought

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **chrome.runtime.onSuspend.addListener( function )** method to specify some code to run when the user quits the app. As stated in the chrome documentation, any code running or triggered in the background/event page will keep the program alive for a short time to allow these processes to end. Remember to register this event listener method in your background/event page before the user has a chance to quit.

Additional information here:
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onSuspend